# If extra dimensional beings came to Earth- how many beings and how long to disrupts all major civilisations on Earth

Tags: apocalypse

Extra-dimensional beings are the same size and speed as human (fast walking). They walk in random direction- they have no idea that they came to Earth (accident on their world) and arrived at random locations anywhere over Earth.  They  are immune to all Earth-based energy or matter effects- all transferred to the other world. They  destroy everything they contact on any side. They make an atom thick vacuum around them and are essentially voids. They walk on water and of course go through everything. How many and how long would it take for them to absolutely decimate civilisation- assuming they don't destroy the biosphere? They are bound by gravity and other forces in their own world. Their planet is geophysically and astrophysically the same as Earth- just not hydrophysically- they "apparently"  walk on water on their own world- hence it solves all your movement issues. They don't tire because they absorb some energy that passes through them. Imagine one day you are on your world and an accident suddenly spread some of your population all other the place and your world is changed unrecognisable- that is their situation. Humans don't know they are extra-dimensional beings since they just appear and they will seem to be meteorological anomalies expect powerful winds that make observation extremely hard. Answers need to consider the number of being say 1 billion beings.

Comment: It's a bit contradictive: They destroy everything the contact but on the other, they do not destroy the biosphere?

Comment: "They walk on water and of course go through everything." The next contradiction. They must interact with water in order to walk on it...

Comment: No contradiction- Wenherr- the biosphere is enormous- only destroying little bits. Once they destroy civilisation by accident- they change so they are no longer voids.

Comment: If they walk on water, they won´t destroy anything under water?

Comment: Gradually destroy air and water and land- you can estimate the speed.

Comment: Won´t they just fall to the core, destroying the ground beneath them?

Comment: @Daniel Only if they don't spawn on water. /s

Comment: @user2617804: I think you need a little bit on your question. So I understand you want some human sized erasers spawning and moving randomly on earth. How does the moving work? Walking is interaction that relies on friction, contradicting your destroy everything paradigm. Also surface will no mean anything to them as far as I understand the concept. What about gravity? Are they affected by it? Then you need to give at least spawn rate. As it is random, the answer can only be a time-curve of probability in the end.

Comment: in your current explaination of their movement - wouldn´t it suffice to dig a small ditch in the ground an then the beings would quasi walk over you through the air?

Answer (score 2):

To the simplified mathmobile!
Total surface area of Earth is about **510000000 $km^2$** (197 million sq mi). Average human take **0,066 square metres**. For future calculations we will calculate that this earth surface is rectangular with a width of 25 cm and 2040000000000 metres in length. We ignore everything that is above ground level as we need to vacuum the surface not anything that hang above.
Now, average human speed is 1,4m/s but as people can walk even 2,5 m/s we assume that this alien walks with exactly 2 m/s which give us **283333333,3333333 hours** which roughly translate to **32433 years** which translate to

> welp, that's a nice anomaly, but it's nothing bad so why should we care?

And it's all BEFORE we add his randomness in movement and the requirement for him to cover ALL surface.
If you add two of them you won't lower the amount of years by two as their random movement will result in standing on the same surface thrice or even more. The randomness can be calculated as this "earth stripe" can be divided into cells (6800000000000 to be exact) and then you can calculate given time when all cell will be visited at least once.

The easy method would be to calculate how many those being fit into average hurricane surface, lower the speed of the hurricane to this of walking speed and then calculate how much time it would need to cover all earth, give it +25% for the randomness and then you will have time and amount of aliens needed to destroy things.

You have to keep in mind that if the time is larger than few years the destruction could affect smaller countries or civilization but won't affect countries like US (which by now is visited by hurricanes every years in semirandom pattern)

Comment: So hurricanes are actually extra dimensional beings on the war path??? This changes EVERYTHING!!! Good answer

Comment: @BladeWraith Even worst. Is seems that those beings are actually flamingos!

Comment: @szczezokly: We're all doomed!!! run for your LIVES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Infinite.

Once people would realize they are safe under water and in underground bunkers, as well as in the air, they would simply adjust their living conditions to avoid anything permanent on the surface.

Comment: Our civilisations aren't going to survive those changes- there are few submarines, not enormous number of bunkers worldwide and living in air without airports is nonviable.

Comment: We have years to build this, see @SZCZERZO KŁY´s Answer...

Comment: I only asked when global civilisation as we know it will be gone- not anything new.

Comment: No you asked "all civilisation". Maybe you should specify. Especially at what point the current civilization does not longer count as "as we know it" - In my book that would be the moment extra dimensional world-destroying beings arrive, so about instantly or as fast as news travel ...

Comment: Infinite what?  Infinite beings- we are all dead and the Earth is dead.

Comment: only the part of surface matching the surface of the beings home planet is annihilated, as per your scenario.

Comment: "extra dimensional world-destroying beings arrive"- you are assuming we know extra-dimensional being have arrived rather they just suddenly "appear". They have no physical appearance.

Comment: So Things just disappearing into the void is no physical appearance to you? I would be pretty shocked and would drastically change my behavior immediately ...

Comment: Please don´t blame me that your question is incomplete and has logic flaws. At least now you have points to think about and work on, and once you figured out what you actually want to achieve I´m sure you can write a Question that fits and that we can answer. Your scenario is interesting, just need to clarify how you want it to work...